# Find the Last Match in a Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string and a regular expression that I am running against it. But instead of the first match, I am interested in the last match of the Regular Expression.

Is there a quick/easy way to do this?

I am currently using Regex.Matches, which returns a MatchCollection, but it doesn't accept any parameters that will help me, so I have to go through the collection and grab the last one. But it seems there should be an easier way to do this. Is there?

Comment: Match match = matches[matches.Count - 1];

Comment: Use [Right-to-Left Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-18).

Comment: @AlanMoore: Thanks, that worked and was exactly what I was looking for. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET regex flavor allows you to search for matches from right to left instead of left to right.  It's the only flavor I know of that offers such a feature.  It's cleaner and more efficient than the traditional methods, such prefixing the regex with `.*`, or searching out all matches so you can take the last one.

To use it, pass this option when you call `Match()` (or other regex method):

```
RegexOptions.RightToLeft
```

More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_9).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Linq` `LastOrDefault` or `Last` to get the last match from `MatchCollection`.

```
var lastMatch = Regex.Matches(input,"hello") 
                     .OfType<Match>()
                     .LastOrDefault();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQqxSU)

Or, as **@jdweng**  mentioned in the comment, you could even access using index.

```
Match lastMatch = matches[matches.Count - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("REGEX"); 
var v = regex.Match("YOUR TEXT");
string s = v.Groups[v.Count - 1].ToString();
```